# Package EntityFramework.Extended update error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I installed the package `EntityFramowork.Extended`. This package extends the functionality of Entity Framework. But when I use it I have this problem:

> An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: One or more errors occurred.

Code for my WebAPI controller:

```
public void Put(int id, TableModal idModel)
{
    db.TableModals.Where(a => a.Id == id).Update(a => idModel);
}
```

Comment: Could you give some details about the error?

Comment: what details? I have current version EntityFramowork and EntityFramowork.Extended(may be EntityFramowork.Extended do not support last EntityFramowork?).

Comment: This information about the error of all.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll is a very common error. To see more about the error you need to look in the inner exception.

Comment: I got this error when I attempted to perform a bulk update but with no data to update. Is your idModel populated and is there an associated record in the database to be updated?